# Import .so library in Android project

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I reuse a project in Github; In fact, i have a .so library in C++, so i want to import this library in java part by  using native function. the problem is Java part can not load this library; i search a lot of questions concerned this issue, but it doesn't resolve mine. 
Here the structure of project:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, use text instead of pictures of text.

Comment: Android Studio cannot understand that the native methods are implemented in the imported so file. You should not be worried about these warnings unless your project had runtime problems loading the library.

Comment: Please specify your errors are compile error/run time errors if run time erros then include stack-trace in question.

Answer (score 0):

From your project tree structure,I found that your JNI Interface file(MyNDK) is in your project package.If it is downloaded from a external library project then you should use same package structure.For example

> if the Interface file have package name `com.library.jni` and
>   Interface name `LibMonoInterface.java` then you should use same
>   package name and same interface file otherwise it will not work

Comment: I don't really understand your answers. Can you precise it a little. Here, i completely reuse a project from Github, nothing from my own. And i think all files are included in com.example.castoryan.orb , it means that they are used in the same package name ? So what do i have to change in this case ?

Comment: Please specify which project you are using(github url).